# Simple SSE loop slower than non-SSE version

Tags: c++, gcc, sse

I am trying to compare SSE float[4] addition to standard float[4] addition. As a demo I compute the sum of the summed components, with and without SSE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Point4
{
  Point4()
  {
    data[0] = 0;
    data[1] = 0;
    data[2] = 0;
    data[3] = 0;
  }

  float data[4];
};

void Standard()
{
  Point4 a;
  a.data[0] = 1.0f;
  a.data[1] = 2.0f;
  a.data[2] = 3.0f;
  a.data[3] = 4.0f;

  Point4 b;
  b.data[0] = 1.0f;
  b.data[1] = 6.0f;
  b.data[2] = 3.0f;
  b.data[3] = 5.0f;

  float total = 0.0f;
  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 1e9; ++i)
  {
    for(unsigned int component = 0; component < 4; ++component)
    {
      total += a.data[component] + b.data[component];
    }
  }

  std::cout << "total: " << total << std::endl;
}

void Vectorized()
{
  typedef float v4sf __attribute__ (( vector_size(4*sizeof(float)) ));

  v4sf a;
  float* aPointer = (float*)&a;
  aPointer[0] = 1.0f; aPointer[1] = 2.0f; aPointer[2] = 3.0f; aPointer[3] = 4.0f;

  v4sf b;
  float* bPointer = (float*)&b;
  bPointer[0] = 1.0f; bPointer[1] = 6.0f; bPointer[2] = 3.0f; bPointer[3] = 5.0f;

  v4sf result;
  float* resultPointer = (float*)&result;
  resultPointer[0] = 0.0f;
  resultPointer[1] = 0.0f;
  resultPointer[2] = 0.0f;
  resultPointer[3] = 0.0f;

  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 1e9; ++i)
  {
    result += a + b; // Vectorized operation
  }

  // Sum the components of the result (this is done with the "total += " in the Standard() loop
  float total = 0.0f;
  for(unsigned int component = 0; component < 4; ++component)
  {
    total += resultPointer[component];
  }
  std::cout << "total: " << total << std::endl;
}

int main()
{

//  Standard();

  Vectorized();

  return 0;
}
```

However, the code seems to be faster (~.2 seconds) with the standard method than with the vectorized (~.4 seconds) method. Is it because of the for loop to sum the v4sf values? Is there a better operation I can use to time the difference between these two techniques and still compare the output to make sure there were no differences between the two?

Comment: .2 and .4 seconds seem to be quite low for uncertainty errors. How did you measure it? Make sure that you only measure the test loop in-program, not the whole program runtime, which includes lots of other stuff. Also make sure that your compiler is properly configured to properly use the intrinsics and take care of alignment.

Comment: I compiled with -O3. @PlasmaHH they are low, but I did it 5x each and they were pretty constant. By "use the intrinsics", do you mean use -msse2? (I did). I just used 'time' from a terminal to time them - one time(s) compiled with only the Vectorized() call in main uncommented, and the other time(s) with only the Standard() call in main uncommented.

Comment: The SSE part of your vectorized loop is insignificant compared to the rest of the loop (one SSE arithmetic instruction versus > 10 scalar instructions).

Comment: `time` from the terminal isn't a good way to profile things. Use a proper profiler.

Comment: Also, it appears you're only making a single call to the routine in question, which makes the rest of the process run time be significant statistical noise. You might try running each in a loop of 1,000,000 iterations or so, and time that instead.

Comment: Using a `double` as limit in a counting loop is generally a bad idea. The C standard requires a conversion from int to double in each iteration. gcc might be able to optimize it away - but even then this can easily introduce bugs.

Comment: @drhirsch - isn't the compiler smart enough to just convert the 1e6 to an int once?

Comment: @twalberg - the two functions each have loops (i < 1e6) inside of them, is that not the same thing?

Comment: @Paul R - how did you get 10? Is it 4 (one addition each time through the loop) + 4 (one comparison to check the loop condition each time through the loop) + ?

Comment: @DavidDoria Ooops... My bad - I was looking for a test loop around the calling site, not within the functions themselves....

Comment: @David: It looks like at least 10 scalar instructions - note that there are loads and stores going on as well as all the more obvious arithmetic operations. Check the assembly output from your compiler to see the actual number of instructions. The bottom line though is that the number of SSE instructions (1) is dwarfed by all the scalar code.

Answer (score 1):

Then reason your version is slower as SSE is that you have to unpack from an SSE register to a scalar register 4 times every iteration, which has more of an overhead than what you gain from the vectorized addition. Look at the disassembly and you should get a clearer picture.

I think what you want to do is the following (which is faster with SSE):

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 1e6; ++i)
{
    result += a + b; // Vectorized operation
}

// Sum the components of the result (this is done with the "total += " in the Standard() loop
for(unsigned int component = 0; component < 4; ++component)
{
    total += resultPointer[component];
}
```

Also the following might be even faster:

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 1e6/4; ++i)
{
    result0 += a + b; // Vectorized operation
    result1 += a + b; // Vectorized operation
    result2 += a + b; // Vectorized operation
    result3 += a + b; // Vectorized operation
}

// Sum the components of the result (this is done with the "total += " in the Standard() loop
for(unsigned int component = 0; component < 4; ++component)
{
    total += resultPointer0[component];
    total += resultPointer1[component];
    total += resultPointer2[component];
    total += resultPointer3[component];
}
```

Comment: I get the first version - that makes sense, I'll try it out. But I don't understand what is going on in the second version? Why are you doing the same thing 4 times in the first loop?

Comment: Ok, I'm really confused now. Using your first suggested method (http://ideone.com/N4rHy), here are my timings: 

With -msse2
Vectorized() : 1.7s
Standard() : 4.0s

This is what I'd expect - great! However,
WithOUT -msse2
Vectorized() : 15.4s
Standard() : 7.4s

Why is this backwards? I would expect pretty much the same performance without -msse2 from Vectorized() and Standard(), would you not?

Comment: actually, I just realized I am not getting the same result. Vectorized() outputs "total: 5.70425e+08", while Standard() outputs "total: 2.5e+10".

Comment: I thought I found the problem - 'result' was not initialized to zero. But even after adding:   resultPointer[0] = 0.0f;
  resultPointer[1] = 0.0f;
  resultPointer[2] = 0.0f;
  resultPointer[3] = 0.0f; , the output of Vectorized() is unchanged (and different from Standard() ).

Comment: Gahhh there was a huge bug (the nested loops in the Standard() function had the same counter name), but even with that fix (edited in the original post), the outputs are still different. I stepped through a few iterations and they both seem to be working correctly - is there some kind of overflow problem or something?

Comment: The Standard() and Vectorized() functions here: http://ideone.com/dwsv9 produce the same result for numberOfIterations = 1e5 and 1e6, but at 1e7 the results start to vary ( Standard() total: 2.5e+08 and Vectorized() total: 2.50679e+08 )

Comment: @DavidDoria: It might be that your compiler alrdy vectorizes the "Standard" loop for you automatically.

Comment: ronag: but the runtime is twice as fast (which makes it seem like one is vectorized and one is not). I guess there are just some weird float precision things going on - any better ideas for code that doesn't have to add so high but still doesn't get "optimized out" and can demonstrate the vectorization speed improvement?